# How can I merge two or more features into a single feature in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

Let's say I had a module with four features:

- `My.Module.FeatureA.PartA`
- `My.Module.FeatureA.PartB`
- `My.Module.FeatureA.PartC`
- `My.Module.FeatureB`

I want to refactor my module so that it only has two features by moving the first three features into a new feature called `My.Module.FeatureA`.

To do this, I'd:

- update the module manifest file
- change the `OrhcardFeature` attributes on each of my classes
- merge any migration files into a single migration

I can see a problem in doing this- because we now have a single migration with a different class name to the previous 'old' three migrations. Surely Orchard will try to run the new migration (as it won't have previously run), and this will cause errors when trying to perform actions such as creating a table that one of the old migrations originally created.

What is the best way to go about merging features in Orchard?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the new migrations in a way that they won't fail if they are invoked multiple times. Alternatively, if that's too much work, you can modify the Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord table and insert a record for your new migration with the latest version of the migration. That way Orchard won't run your new migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do want the new migrations to run. The automatic mapping of record classes relies on a naming convention for the tables that includes the feature name. If you merge features, then the table names will change. That means that you will want to :

1. recreate the tables for the moved features, so that the new tables have the right names and can be properly mapped.
2. move existing data from the old table to the new ones. This has to be done in plain SQL because you'll have to work around the conventions as they can't be both active at the same time. Look at the Upgrade module for examples of that.
3. optionally, drop the old tables.